# Using DOM in AdonisJS with Playwright for PDF generation

Tags: dom, playwright, jsdom, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

I'm seeking guidance on utilizing the DOM in AdonisJS for a specific use case.

I understand that AdonisJS is primarily designed for server-side development and may not automatically include TypeScript definitions for the document object and other DOM elements, as these concepts are specific to the browser environment.

However, my current project involves using the Playwright library for PDF generation. I need to evaluate HTML classes through the $evaluate method, which requires access to DOM types. Even when attempting to use the JSDOM library, I encounter a definition error.

I'd greatly appreciate any assistance or insights into this matter. Thank you in advance; I'm a bit stuck at this stage.

```
import { inject } from '@adonisjs/core'
import { HttpContext } from '@adonisjs/core/http'
import { chromium } from 'playwright'
import { ConfigPdfInteface } from '../interface/config_pdf_interface.js'
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom'
@inject()
export default class PlaywrightService {
  constructor(protected ctx: HttpContext) {}

  async generatePdfPlaywright(
    response: HttpContext['response'],
    path: string,
    documents: any,
    config: ConfigPdfInteface
  ) {
    try {
      const browser = await chromium.launch({
        headless: true,
      })

      const page = await browser.newPage()

      await page.emulateMedia({ media: 'print' })

      const html = await this.ctx.view.render(`${path}`, documents)
      await page.setContent(html, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle',
      })

      const selector = '#someSelector'
      const bodySize = await page.evaluate((p) => {
        const { document } = new JSDOM(html).window
        console.log('document', document)
        const body = document?.querySelector(p)
        const minHeight = window.getComputedStyle(body!).minHeight
        return minHeight
      }, selector)

      console.log('bodySize', bodySize)

      const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf(config)

      await browser.close()

      response.header('Content-type', 'application/pdf')
      response.header('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=example.pdf')

      response.send(pdfBuffer)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      response.status(500).send('PDF Error')
    }
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
page.evaluate: ReferenceError: JSDOM is not defined
    at eval (eval at evaluate (:226:30), <anonymous>:2:38)
    at UtilityScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:228:17)
    at UtilityScript.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:44)
    at PlaywrightService.generatePdfPlaywright
```

Comment: Why do you need JSDOM in the browser? You have the actual DOM! Remove `const { document } = new JSDOM(html).window`

Comment: Oh, maybe it's because I'm just getting to know Adonis but I need it to get the total number of pages and to evaluate sizes, with just the Playwright library I can't do that and with pure HTML and CSS I couldn't achieve it, that's why I came to this Possible solution

Comment: Or if you use JSDOM, do it without Playwright, directly in Node. Using Playwright basically invalidates the need for JSDOM. I'm not clear what you're trying to do though.

Comment: The issue is that when I tried to access HTML elements directly in my service and wanted to evaluate the DOM using Playwright, I encountered an error. That's why I asked my question. However, as you mentioned, it resolved the problem. I inquired because I need to perform some evaluations with the PDF browser, and I received an error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might be experiencing an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Try asking about fundamental problem X, rather than attempted solution Y which seems to be based on a misunderstanding, and not a good way to go about solving X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish (seems likely a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676)), but in any case, there's no sense in running JSDOM in a browser. The whole point of JSDOM is to simulate the browser DOM in Node. But with Playwright, you get access to the real DOM in an actual webpage. Use it--that's the purpose of Playwright!

Even if you wanted to use JSDOM in the browser, you'd have to explicitly add a script tag or pass the variable into `evaluate` (it wouldn't work since you can only pass serializable values). The variable `JSDOM` will be undefined once the `evaluate` callback is executed in the browser process.

So

```js
const selector = '#someSelector'
const bodySize = await page.evaluate((p) => {
  const { document } = new JSDOM(html).window
  console.log('document', document)
  const body = document?.querySelector(p)
  const minHeight = window.getComputedStyle(body!).minHeight
  return minHeight
}, selector)
```

becomes:

```js
const selector = "#someSelector";
const bodySize = await page.$eval(selector, el =>
  getComputedStyle(el).minHeight
);
```

Minimal, runnable example:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.42.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<p style="min-height: 42px"></p></body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const selector = "p";
  const bodySize = await page.$eval(selector, el =>
    getComputedStyle(el).minHeight
  );
  console.log(bodySize); // => 42px
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

If `selector` can't be found, `$eval` will throw. You can catch it and handle accordingly if you expect it to be missing, or wrap the code in a condition:

```js
const selector = "#someSelector";
const el = await page.$(selector);

if (el) {
  const bodySize = await el.evaluate(el =>
    getComputedStyle(el).minHeight
  );
}
```

or wait for it:

```js
const selector = "#someSelector";
const el = await page.waitForSelector(selector);
const bodySize = await el.evaluate(el =>
  getComputedStyle(el).minHeight
);
```

But `bodySize` is never used in your code.